# log4net not logging when the exe is running from startup but works fine when started manually

Tags: c#, console-application, log4net

log4net is not generating the log file nor writing logs into the file when the application is running from the registry start up. But when the application is executed manually, the files are created.

The start up registry key is created in path "[HKEY_LOCAL_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run". When the user logs into the machine the application has to run automatically.
Have a separate log4net.config file for all the log configuration
The log file is created in the user roaming profile. 
Things tried:
1. I tried saving in some general path also like (C:\logs\app) still the logs are not created.
2. Run the .exe from command prompt both from user context and administrator privileges, No use.

#### Log4net Config

```
 <log4net>
     <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" 
       type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
     <file value="${APPDATA}\app\app.txt"/>
     <appendToFile value="true" />
     <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
     <rollInterval value="Week"/>
     <DatePattern value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
     <rollSizeKB value="50000"/>
     <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
     <countDirection value="1" />
     <staticLogFileName value="true" />
     <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="[%date{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%-5level] 
     [%-5.70logger] - %message%newline"/>
     </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
     <level value="ALL" />
     <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
   </log4net>
```

#### Initialising the config

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

I expect to see a log file at path C:\Users[User]\AppData\Roaming\app\app.txt" but it is not there. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you 100% certain the app is actually running?  Could you pop up a message box or something?

Comment: My guess would be that the startup directory is different when running as AutoRun, and you're passing a relative path to the log4net config. I suggest adding some test code which uses `File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\path.txt", Environment.CurrentDirectory)` to see what the working directory is. If my guess is not correct, dump the log4net config debug output to a file using something like [this](https://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/) and you should be able to see what the problem is.

Comment: The application as such runs perfectly. Only issue is with logs

Comment: Yes, I understand that. And if you want to know why log4net isn't logging, you have to a) make sure it's picking up the config file and b) if so, check the internal debugging output.

Comment: Hello Stuartd,
Can you guide me how to fetch the path of the log file after the configuration is initialised with below line of code. 
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

Answer (score 0):

Try with absolute path for your log file and see if it helps. I had the same problem where executing the exe manually logs the data but when run through command prompt, keeps mum.